# Page description on hover in dropdown menu in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create a functionality of a dropdown menu which has a small description in sideway column when hovering over a link? Can it be accomplished by pure CSS?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNyORv

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-header-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Two Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">title 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">title 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li>This is visible by default or when hovering over Title 1</li>
                                <li>This is hidden but visible when hovering over Title 2</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
</nav>
<!--/.navbar-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are after is typically provided using [Bootstrap Tooltip](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp) or [Bootstrap Popover](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp). Both are fully `style`-able and customizable. Besides, they are mobile friendly (see sidenote(s) at end of answer).

Alternatively, you can use something like this. Please note you have to adjust the `min-height` of your `.columns-2>.col-xs-6` to a value big enough to fit the descriptions without a scrollbar (if any of the descriptions is large enough to need it):

```css
.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
 min-width: 400px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
 padding: 5px 15px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.multi-column-dropdown {
 list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 line-height: 1.428571429;
 color: #333;
 white-space: normal;
}
 

.multi-column-dropdown .columns-2 {
  position: relative;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 7px 15px;
}
.columns-2>.col-xs-6 {
  /* adjust this to accomodate the height of your descriptions on all screens */
  min-height: 100px;
  
}
.multi-column-dropdown li:first-child .li-description {
  display: inline-block;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li .li-description {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li:hover .li-description {
  display: inline-block;
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .multi-column-dropdown li .li-description {
    background-color: white;
  }
  .columns-2>.col-xs-6 {
  /* adjust this to accomodate the height of your descriptions on all screens */
     min-height: 160px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-header-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Two Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                    
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">title 1</a><div class="li-description">This is visible by default or when hovering over Title 1</div></li>
                                <li><a href="#">title 2</a><div class="li-description">This is hidden but visible when hovering over Title 2. It is a longer description and we need <code>min-height</code> on <code>.columns-2>.col-xs-6</code> so it doesn't create a scrollbar...</div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        
                    
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
</nav>
<!--/.navbar-->
```

Sidenotes on your codepen:

- You are loading two versions of jQuery. That's a big `NO NO`.
- You are supposed to use `.row` inside a parent with `margin: 0 15px;`, such as `.container`. This generates an unwanted horizontal scrollbar on your row. Pay closer attention to Bootstrap's markup.

Sidenote on your UI architecture:

- More than half of today's internet users are browsing from a touch device. How are they supposed to `hover` and see the description?

Comment: Thank you, I will explore the code. I was aware Bootstrap has code for tooltips, but I never thought it could be useful in this example. As for mobile users, this description is only necessary for desktop users, I will try to hide it on other screens